# I want to create a photo gallery in php using array or session/ cookies

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i want solution for my problem.

[image]

in this image was a front end i need function behind on this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time and read though the FAQ. SO is not a coding service where you dump your tasks, but a platform to help you with specific problems with *your* implementation. Please show us, what you tried so far - then people will try to nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: but sir my code should not be uploaded on stack flow

Comment: are you developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can use bootstrap to develop gallery and php to get images dynamicalyy.
>
> Instead of putting static image use php to load images from the database or url.
>
> SEE OUR WORK

```
                        <span class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3  title-service-inner">
                            Vestibulum elementum ex ullamcorper ligula vulputate
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/slider1.jpg"
                                     alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/slider2.jpg"
                                     alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/slider3.jpg"
                                     alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/bg_image1.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/bg_image2.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/bg_image3.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/bg_image.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="/theme_mytheme/static/src/img/bg_image5.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: but i use session and array

Comment: <?php
        if ($key==$gal_nam) {
            $data=array(
            'gallery-name'=>$gal_nam,
            'pic'=>array('img/gallery/'. $gal_img)
            );
            $_SESSION['data']['gallery-name']['pic']=$data;
        }
        else {
            $data=array(
            'gallery-name'=>$gallery_name,
            'pic'=>array('img/gallery/'. $gal_img)
            );
            $_SESSION['data']['gallery-name']['pic']=$data;
        }
?>